# A defined data type not defined?

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

I need some help trying to understand why these definitions

```
data SegmentList
    = SegmentList SegmentlistHeader [Segment]
    | AugmentedSegmentList SegmentlistHeader [AugmentedSegment]
    deriving (Show)

data SegmentlistHeader
    = SegmentlistHeader DatabaseName Query LabelType TimeStamp
    deriving (Show)

data Segment
    = Segment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session Checksum
    | AugmentedSegment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session Checksum Metadata
    deriving (Show)

type DatabaseName = String
type SegmentLabel = String
type SegmentStart = Double
type SegmentEnd = Double
type Session = String
type LabelType = String
type Query = String
type TimeStamp = String
type Checksum = String
type Metadata = [(String, String)]
```

result in this error message:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `AugmentedSegment'
A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean -XDataKinds?
```

while this :

```
data UmeQueryPart
    = LabelInLabelType String [String] String
    | LabelType String
    | UmeQueryDominance UmeQueryPart UmeQueryPart String
    | UmeQuerySequence UmeQueryPart UmeQueryPart String
    | UmeQueryIntersect [UmeQueryPart]
    | UmeQueryUnion [UmeQueryPart]
    deriving Show
```

compiles like a charm. I'm obviously not skilled enough to see the difference...

Comment: What line is the error coming from?

Comment: I don't see it either - is there something missing (the part that yields this error) - there seems to be more missing - for example where is `SegmentPlus` (or do I just miss it)?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was playing with differnt versions of the thing. Still the same error though. It should now be complete. The error comes from the line where `[AugmentedSegment]`, right where the 'A' is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your edit, you have

```
data SegmentList
    = SegmentList SegmentlistHeader [Segment]
    | AugmentedSegmentList SegmentlistHeader [AugmentedSegment]
    deriving (Show)

data Segment
    = Segment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session Checksum
    | AugmentedSegment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session Checksum Metadata
    deriving (Show)
```

The problem specifically is from the second constructor of `SegmentList`:

```
AugmentedSegmentList SegmentlistHeader [AugmentedSegment]
```

Here you've said that `AugmentedSegmentList` contains a list of `AugmentedSegment`, but `AugmentedSegment` is a constructor of `Segment`, it is not a type.  When defining a data type, it can only reference other *types*, not other *constructors*.  You could change it to

```
AugmentedSegmentList SegmentlistHeader [Segment]
```

But this probably isn't exactly what you want.  Since your `Segment` and `AugmentedSegment` constructors are identical other than the addition of the `Metadata` field, I would instead recommend having

```
data Segment
    = Segment SegmentLabel SegmentStart SegmentEnd Session Checksum
    deriving (Show)

data AugmentedSegment
    = AugmentedSegment Segment Metadata
    deriving (Show)
```

Then you can have a list of only `AugmentedSegment`s which is enforced by the type system, but it also means that you can't pass in an `AugmentedSegment` to a function that accepts a `Segment`.  Since these appear to be different things, this shouldn't be a problem.  If it is, you can always just pass in the contained `Segment` field from an `AugmentedSegment` into the function you're concerned with, or you can alter your function to accept a value of type `Either Segment AugmentedSegment` instead.

---

In summary, when you have something like

```
data MyType = MyConstructor FieldA FieldB FieldC
```

The `MyType` symbol is the name of the type, the `MyConstructor` symbol is a constructor, you can think of it as a function that returns something of type `MyType`, and the `FieldN`s symbols all have to be existing *types* or can recursively refer to `MyType`, they can not be other constructors.  This is what caused the error you're seeing.